# How can I continue a gem install process

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Im trying to install the phashion which needs to compile the pHash library. pHash depends on libjpeg. The gem installs fine on Linux boxes but I have some problems on my Mac (Lion 10.7.3) with it:

I did install libjpeg via MacPorts, but when I run `gem install phashion` the process fails, complaining about the missing libjpeg.

This is the error I get:

```
gcc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin11.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin11.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -I/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4/ext/phashion_ext/include  -L/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4/ext/phashion_ext/lib  -x c++   -c phashion_ext.c
cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o phashion_ext.bundle phashion_ext.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4/ext/phashion_ext/lib -L/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4/ext/phashion_ext/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby   -lpthread -lpHash_gem -lstdc++ -ljpeg
ld: library not found for -ljpeg
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: library not found for -ljpeg
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccCwUAM1.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [phashion_ext.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4/ext/phashion_ext/gem_make.out
```

libjpeg lies in `/opt/local/lib`. So I had a look at the gem's makefile and added the library path to the ldflags. Now make runs fine and the library seems to compile.

What now? When I run `gem install phashion` again, my makefile gets overwritten.

So how can I start the install process again without losing my changes to the gem?

**PS:** I've tried changing into the gem's directory and run `rake`, but it fails with this error message:

```
WARNING: rake-compiler found compiled files in 'ext/phashion_ext' directory. Please remove them.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/test_*.rb" 
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- phashion_ext (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from ./lib/phashion.rb:33
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from ./test/helper.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4/test/test_phashion.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/phashion-1.0.4/test/test_phashion.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4
rake aborted!
```

Comment: I was able to install this fine on my mac without any additional libs. My suggestion: `gem uninstall phasion` and then `gem install phasion` ... do you get the message Building Native extensions. This could  take a while... ?

Comment: Yes, removed the gem and reinstalled, but no luck. I've updated my question with the error I get and added my OS version (Lion 10.7.3). Did you have to install libjpeg and did you use MacPorts (or Brew)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the latest XCode?

1. Install XCode 4.4
2. Install command line tools from XCode 4.4 Preferences dialog